# Are there any reverse recipe caluclator / generators online?

Tags: recipe, calculations, software

I have a bunch of small amounts of leftover specialty grains ranging from 3 ounces to about 8 ounces of various types.  I'd like to brew something with them.  Are there any good sites out there that might allow me to enter the grains I have and suggest a recipe style that might come from the grains I entered?

Comment: This would have been a feature of www.BrewSession.com (probably around v3.0) but development on that has pretty much halted.

Comment: I'd be interested in writing some code for this sort of tool.

Comment: I can offer some design services.

Comment: PJ knows where to find me. Matt, drop me an email: dean@brewsession.com

Comment: Cleaning up tags: Changed recipes -> recipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Beer Calculus" is great. http://beercalculus.hopville.com/recipe

This calculator has an EXTENSIVE selection of malt/fermentation (preloaded OG/FG and color based on sugars), hops (with typical AA %), yeast strains (ale/lager, dry/liquid, and flocculation level), and boils/primary/secondary add-ins (lots of them!).

Great calculator where you can select target beer styles or make your own style by helping you gauge sweet/bitter, color, alcohol, and make a shopping list!

*This is not a reverse calculator, but does allow selection from many sugars/fermentables.  From there you can see what else you would need to buy/add to tailor to your liking.

Comment: I'd vote for this thrice if I could. Thanks Stephen

Comment: After playing around with the target style feature a bit, I've decided to accept this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen what you are talking about before. Its a shame because I have heard several people ask for it.  You might be able to seach the BeerTools recipe database for a single ingredient, but I don't remember.  Here are some links to popular online recipe generating calculators.  Although none of them are "*reverse*" calulators.

Good luck.  My only other solution would be to post what you have on a typical brewing forum site and ask for feedback and recipes that way.  You'll find some creative solutions that way I am sure.

[BeerTools Online](http://www.beertools.com/) has one. You have to create a user account, but its free.
[Tasty Brew](http://www.tastybrew.com/calculators/recipe.html) has a decent calculator.
I used to use [The BeerRecipator](http://hbd.org/recipator/) a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Beersmith lets you [search for recipes based on your inventory](http://www.beersmith.com/advanced%5Ffeatures.htm) (scroll down to "Search By Ingredient"). If you don't already have a huge bank of recipes in Beersmith, they have [recipe packs](http://www.beersmith.com/recipes.htm) to pre-populate your database.

Alternatively, there's always [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=en&q=%224+oz+crystal+60L%22+%228+oz+carapils%22&aq=f&oq=&aqi=).

Comment: Nice use of Google